Адаптивный UI в Godot


Здравствуйте, возникла проблемка с Progress bar в Godot.
Мне нужно подстраивать свой интерфейс под разные разрешения экрана мобильных устройств.
У TextureRect выбрать Stretch mode: Keep aspect centered, то он будет пропорционально уменьшать изображение, но сам TextureRect остается таким же по высоте. К TextureRect у меня привязан ProgressBar.
Хочу чтобы при изменении размеров экрана ProgressBar уменьшался с TextureRect`ом.
Помогите если не сложно, за ранее спасибо.
Upd
У меня будет несколько таких TextureRect, они будут находится в HBoxContainer, который находится в ScrollContainer: ScrollContainer -> HboxContainer -> TextureRect1, TextureRect2...
